# Absolute URL in button JSF

Tags: javascript, button, jsf-2

I have this button in header that I include in many page:

```
<input type="button" value="My Button" onclick="window.location.href='mypage.xhtml'"
```

It use relative path and it works if the caller page is in the same directory.
How can I use absolute path or use commandButton tag ?
I tried with:

```
/mypage.xhtml
```

Don't work (404 error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let EL print the [context path](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29) dynamically. It'll become relative to the domain root.

```
<input type="button" value="My Button" onclick="window.location.href='#{request.contextPath}/mypage.xhtml'">
```

Or, better, just use JSF's own [`<h:button>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/button.html) component which generates the same HTML anyway wherein you don't need to worry about the context path.

```
<h:button value="My Button" outcome="/mypage.xhtml" />
```

If you need to pass any request parameters, you can use `<f:param>` for that.

```
<h:button value="My Button" outcome="/mypage.xhtml">
    <f:param name="foo" value="bar" />
</h:button>
```

Don't use the `<h:commandButton>`. It doesn't send a normal GET request, but a POST request which you'd need to redirect and thus you effectively end up with two HTTP requests wherein all request parameters are lost in the second one.

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to use the JSF commandButton to travel to some page in your project you need to use the action attribute, you can even pass parameters:

```
<h:commandButton action="/details.jsf?faces-redirect=true" value="details">
    <f:attribute name="id" value="#{bean.id}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

If you want to travel to a page outside of your app you will need to add some extra java code somewhere in a backing bean and then trigger it from the front end.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("http://google.com";);
```

*Note:You don't need javascript for this task*